# HEIFからJPEGに変換する公式のインターフェイス

Tags: swift, objective-c

初心者の質問で、情報に不足あるかもしれませんが、ご容赦頂きたく存じます。
■質問
HEIF→JPEGに変換してくれる公式なインターフェースは存在しますでしょうか？
ネットで色々と調べては見たのですが、そのような情報が見つからず
存在しないような気が致しました。

Comment: タグに swift や objective-c とありますが、こちらの言語に限ったご質問ということでしょうか？

Comment: `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`でHEIFファイルを開き、`UIImage`を`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`でJPEGデータに変換するというシンプルな方法ではダメですか？

Comment: 情報頂き有難うございます。なるほどで御座います。こちらの方法を実装できるか挑戦致します！

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ALAssetは割と昔にDeprecatedですが一応参考ソースを。

```
NSString *asset_uri = [@"assets-library:" stringByAppendingString:asset_url];
NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:asset_uri];

ALAssetsLibrary *assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl resultBlock:^(ALAsset *myasset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *myerror) {
    // error
}];
```

Comment: なるほどで御座います。大変参考になりました！何から何まで申し訳ございませんでした。有難うございました！！無事に解決致しました！

Answer (score 2):

私も探しましたがありませんでした。
今の所自分で変換するようにしています。

```
NSData *imageData = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"imageData"];
if([[ext lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"heic"]) {
    NSLog(@"HEIC Image convert.");
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
    NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
    NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];
    NSMutableDictionary *exifDictionary = [[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSMutableData *timageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)timageData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil);
    NSMutableDictionary *tmetadata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [tmetadata setObject:exifDictionary forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)tmetadata);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
    CFRelease(dest);

    // カメラロールに保存
    SEL sel = @selector(savingImageIsFinished:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, sel, nil);
}
```

Comment: ソースまで頂き有難うございました！大変参考になりました。こちらで、変換は可能かと存じます。そちら以外に分からない箇所が御座いまして。もしお分かればとご教授頂きたいので御座いますが、ALAssetから NSData を作成する方法もご教授頂けますと幸いで御座います。

Comment: @kkanzaki ALAsset に関する質問は今回のご質問と内容が別になってくるかと思います。別の質問として新しく投稿して頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 承知致しました。ご指摘頂き有難うございます。そのようにさせて頂きます